# Android virtual keyboard appears twice when changing keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Recently we've experienced our Android virtual keyboard appearing twice on the `Change keyboard` list. Now I've made sure there is no debug version or similar installed, so I'm **absolutely** sure there is only 1 version of the app/keyboard installed.

The glitch actually appear already on the `Available virtual keyboard` list where the supported languages under our virtual keyboard shows twice.

The issue can be fixed if we reformat the device (not very useable for our users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was solved by only having 1 subtype defined in the xml that is referenced in meta-data:

`<service><meta-data android:resource="@xml/reference"></service>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<input-method xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:settingsActivity="com.your.settingsactivity"
    android:supportsSwitchingToNextInputMethod="true"
    >
    <subtype
        android:label="subtype"
        android:imeSubtypeLocale="en_US"
        android:imeSubtypeMode="keyboard" />
</input-method>
```